# Parse large JSON file in Nodejs and handle each object independently

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I need to read a large JSON file (around 630MB) in Nodejs and insert each object to MongoDB.

I've read the answer here:[Parse large JSON file in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874096/parse-large-json-file-in-nodejs).

However, answers there are handling the JSON file line by line, instead of handling it object by object. Thus, I still don't know how to get an object from this file and operate it.

I have about 100,000 this kind of objects in my JSON file.

Data Format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0000000",
    "name": "Donna Blak",
    "livingSuburb": "Tingalpa",
    "age": 53,
    "nearestHospital": "Royal Children's Hospital",
    "treatments": {
        "19890803": {
            "medicine": "Stomach flu B",
            "disease": "Stomach flu"
        },
        "19740112": {
            "medicine": "Progeria C",
            "disease": "Progeria"
        },
        "19830206": {
            "medicine": "Poliomyelitis B",
            "disease": "Poliomyelitis"
        }
    },
    "class": "patient"
  },
 ...
]
```

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is a nice module named ['stream-json'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) that does exactly what you want.

> It can parse JSON files far exceeding available memory.

and

> StreamArray handles a frequent use case: a huge array of relatively small objects similar to Django-produced database dumps. It streams array components individually taking care of assembling them automatically.

Here is a modern example parsing an arbitrarily large JSON array. It uses `import` statements and [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of), which supports `return`ing or `break`ing from:

```js
import parser from 'stream-json';
import StreamArray from 'stream-json/streamers/StreamArray';
import Chain from 'stream-chain';

async function importJson(filePath) {
  const pipeline = new Chain([
    fs.createReadStream(filePath),
    parser(),
    new StreamArray(),
  ]);

  for await (const { value } of pipeline) {
    await doSomethingWith(value);  // the JSON array element
  }
}
```

### 2018

Here is a very basic example using stream events:

```js
const StreamArray = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const jsonStream = StreamArray.withParser();

//You'll get json objects here
//Key is an array-index here
jsonStream.on('data', ({key, value}) => {
    console.log(key, value);
});

jsonStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('All done');
});

const filename = path.join(__dirname, 'sample.json');
fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(jsonStream.input);
```

If you'd like to do something more complex e.g. process one object after another sequentially (keeping the order) and apply some async operations for each of them then you could do the custom Writeable stream like this:

```js
const StreamArray = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray');
const {Writable} = require('stream');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'sample.json'));
const jsonStream = StreamArray.withParser();

const processingStream = new Writable({
    write({key, value}, encoding, callback) {
        //Save to mongo or do any other async actions

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(value);
            //Next record will be read only current one is fully processed
            callback();
        }, 1000);
    },
    //Don't skip this, as we need to operate with objects, not buffers
    objectMode: true
});

//Pipe the streams as follows
fileStream.pipe(jsonStream.input);
jsonStream.pipe(processingStream);

//So we're waiting for the 'finish' event when everything is done.
processingStream.on('finish', () => console.log('All done'));
```

*Please note:* The examples above are tested for 'stream-json@1.1.3'. For some previous versions (presumably proior to 1.0.0) you might have to:

`const StreamArray = require('stream-json/utils/StreamArray');`

and then

`const jsonStream = StreamArray.make();`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. However, the efficiency is not perfect. It took 130s to read the whole json file with 100,000 objects. Do you think there is a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Stream-json has to be the best json stream reader by far. It saved me from creating my own stream and picking out each object. Thanks for this answer. I had the same issue where i was running out of memory and the only solution was to stream each object at a time.

Comment: @LixingLiang Split the single file into mutiple files and process them parallely, that will give you more efficiency. Bottle neck could be IO operations while reading the file.

Comment: These examples seem to be out of date. I was getting errors with the require and to change to const StreamArray = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray') but then I get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

Comment: @PrestonDocks The package was updated in 2018 with a major version jump (better perf, more utility). Either use a previous major version or read the new doc and update your code accordingly.

Comment: @PrestonDocks, updated the answer, would you mind to take a look.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin updated the answer, check it out please, if still interested.

Comment: how to add depth level while streaming. with above example it only stream with depth level 3. after that i get only type (array or object). like below: "mentions: [Array]"

Comment: Got an error until I added `.js` on the line: `import StreamArray from 'stream-json/streamers/StreamArray.js';`