# How to parse a 500mb json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an upload in my application, which receives an encrypted file. When doing the decryption I'm writing json in another file. After completing this operation I have a 500MB json file.

Note: The properties of my json are dynamic.

How can I parse this json, I read about *stream-json/Parser* but could not implement it.

```
const {parser} = require('stream-json/Parser');

static async _recoverObj(pathAnalise) {

    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(pathAnalise, {encoding: 'utf8', highWaterMark: 1024});

    function createJson(stream) {

        let decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', 'AmbientalRuralBR');

        return new Promise((resolve) => {

            stream.on('data', chunk => {

                let newDecrypt = decipher.update(chunk, 'base64', 'utf8');

                fs.appendFile('./data.json', newDecrypt, function() {
                    console.log('Saved!');
                });

            });

            stream.on('end', () => {

                fs.appendFile('./data.json', '"}', function() {
                    resolve();
                });

            });

        });

    }

    const result = await createJson(readStream);

    function getParse() {

        return new Promise((resolve) => {

            let jsonData = './data.json';
            let pipeline = fs.createReadStream(jsonData).pipe(parser());

            let objectCounter = 0;
            pipeline.on('data', data => {

                data.name === 'startObject' && ++objectCounter

            });

            pipeline.on('end', () => {

                console.log(`Found ${objectCounter} objects.`);
                resolve();

            });

        });

    }

    let dataAnalyze = await getParse();

    return dataAnalyze;

}
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this parse?

**MY SOLUTION:**

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json

```
const json = require('big-json');

static async _recoverObj(pathAnalise) {

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(pathAnalise, {encoding: 'utf8', highWaterMark: 1024 * 2});

    function createJson(stream) {

        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', 'AmbientalRuralBR');

        return new Promise((resolve) => {

            stream.on('data', chunk => {

                var newDecrypt = decipher.update(chunk, 'base64', 'utf8');

                fs.appendFile('./data.json', newDecrypt, function() {
                    console.log('Saved!');
                });

            });

            stream.on('end', () => {
                fs.appendFile('./data.json', '"}', function() {
                    resolve();
                });

            });

        });

    }

    await streamToString(readStream);

    function getParse() {

        return new Promise((resolve) => {

            var jsonData = './max.json';
            var myObj = [];
            const readStream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData);
            const parseStream = json.createParseStream();

            parseStream.on('data', function(pojo) {
                myObj = pojo;
            });

            parseStream.on('end', function() {
                resolve(myObj);
            });

            readStream.pipe(parseStream);

        });

    }

    let dataAnalyze = await getParse();

    return dataAnalyze;

}
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse large JSON file in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874096/parse-large-json-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: See also [so] search [Google javascript node.js parse large json](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+node.js+parse+large+json+file+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score -3):

Once you have the text string containing your json you can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in order to translate it to an object that you can later interact with :

```js
var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.count);
// expected output: 42

console.log(obj.result);
// expected output: true
```

Comment: A string variable does not support the size of my json. If not I would have done it already.