# Remove duplicates from a JSON file of huge size in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, nodejs-stream

I have a huge JSON file of size > 80000 MB containing 700,000,000 records.
File content:

```
     {
        "rows": [
            {"empId":"1014456","blockId":"b6566"},
            {"empId":"1014456","blockId":"b6566"},
            {"empId":"1014457","blockId":"b6556"},
            {"empId":"1014458","blockId":"b6567"}
            ...
            ]
    }
```

I want to remove duplicates using empId as key. How do I do this in nodeJs? Do I need to use streams?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse large JSON file in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874096/parse-large-json-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: 3MB/70.000 records doesn't seem thát huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use lodash uniqby:

```html
_.uniqBy([
            {"empId":"1014456","blockId":"b6566"},
            {"empId":"1014456","blockId":"b6566"},
            {"empId":"1014457","blockId":"b6556"},
            {"empId":"1014458","blockId":"b6567"}
            ...
            ], 'empId');
```

read more about it here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy