# Store big JSON array in Node

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to store a JSON array of objects in a file.

The problem is that if the array is too big, an error is thrown:

```
Invalid String Length
```

This happens when calling `JSON.stringify(array)`.

The max string length in Node is `2 ** 29 - 24`

A good approach is that every object should have a size limit (something like 10 MB per object)

With that in mind, how can I calculate how many objects a file can have?

Comment: possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874096/parse-large-json-file-in-nodejs surely you need to be able to read the file as well, and the solutions here solve both cases. (do take into account the age of some of these answers and the comments)

Comment: @KevinB thank you for referring me to that answer. However, before implementing it, I have some questions:  using that approach, I can create new objects using `appendFile`, but how can I update them? My guess is that I will need to have all the JSON content in memory, is that right?

Comment: If you want arbitrary access you don’t want a giant string and file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late, I wanted to post an answer to this.

So the maximum string length in Node is ~ 500 mb.

The algorithm I'm using is:

```
const maxFileSize = 524288000; // 500 mb

const maxDocumentSize = 1048576; // 1 mb

const maxDocumentSizeWithSpace = maxDocumentSize + 1000; // make room for [] and commas

const maxDocuments = Math.floor(maxFileSize / maxDocumentSizeWithSpace);
```

Now knowing how many documents we can store per file, we can go on.

`maxDocumentSizeWithSpace` is important because the JSON string stored in the file is an array of documents, so characters `,`, `[` and `]` will appear.

Now we'll never get `Invalid String Length` because we can check if a document fits the expected size before writing the file:

```
const file = "./file.json";

const documents = [
  {id: 1, name: "hello"},
  {id: 2, name: "world"},
];

for (const document of documents) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();

  const encoded = encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(document));

  if (encoded.length > maxDocumentSize) {
    throw new Error(`Max document size is ${maxDocumentSize} bytes.`);
  }
}

await fsp.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(documents));
```

Comment: How are you handling larger files that throw an error?  do you split them and join them later?

Comment: @JeremyFiel yes, there's another algorithm to split the content in multiple files `collection/0.json`, `collection/1.json` and so on... I code expecting a document to be up to 1 mb so if I need more space I just rethink my schema to use another `collection`.